# Where I will send background message options

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, angularfire

I'm trying to set background message title in my angular 6 webpage, but I don't know must I send options to this api https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send ? And from which file.

Answer (score 0):

For FCM you need to create a file `firebase-messaging-sw.js` in your root folder,
then get user token using `firebase.messaging()`

```
let messaging=firebase.messaging();
messaging.requestPermission().then(function(){ return messaging.getToken();})
```

then send a post request to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` with

```
//POST: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
//HEADER: Content-Type: application/json
//HEADER: Authorization: key=AIzaSy*******************
{
  "notification":{
    "title":"Notification title",
    "body":"Notification body",
    "sound":"default",
    "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
    "icon":"fcm_push_icon"
  },
  "data":{
    "param1":"value1",
    "param2":"value2"
  },
    "to":"/topics/topicExample",
    "priority":"high",
    "restricted_package_name":""
}
//sound: optional field if you want sound with the notification
//click_action: must be present with the specified value for Android
//icon: white icon resource name for Android >5.0
//data: put any "param":"value" and retreive them in the JavaScript notification callback
//to: device token or /topic/topicExample
//priority: must be set to "high" for delivering notifications on closed iOS apps
//restricted_package_name: optional field if you want to send only to a restricted app package (i.e: com.myapp.test)
```

here is the full documentation for FCM https://github.com/andrehtissot/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated#send-notification-payload-example-rest-api

don't forget to include firebase messaging library

Comment: I use @angular/fire module. I have already create firebase-messaging-sw.js. Also there I add this function messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  var notificationTitle = 'notificationtitle';
  var notificationOptions = {
    body: 'notification from mysite',
    icon: '/myicon.png'
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});

This doesn't change background message, and I read that I need to send to that api.Can I  send it from messaging.service.ts after requesting permission?

Comment: You can send the message from everywhere here is some tutorial what I found for you https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/send-push-notifications-in-angular-with-firebase-cloud-messaging/